# Антиалиасинг в CSS и производительность

Tags: css, шрифты, производительность

Пересев на macbook стал замечать что шрифты на многих сайтах не готовы к экранам с высоким разрешением: они слипаются становясь нечитабельными:
[image: Без антиалиасинга]

Это исправляется добавлением антиалиасинга (что, к слову, занимает всего 2 строки css):

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Результат:

[image: С антиалиасингом]
Почему этого нет даже у крупных сервисов - загадка.
Единственное логическое объяснение приходит из игр, где антиалиасинг негативно влияет на производительность.

Есть ли такое в вебе?

Comment: Нечитабельные шрифты на первом изображении или на втором?

Comment: Там написано что на втором. Согдасен возоможно пример не самый наглядный (собствнно как stackoverflow не лучшее место для стендапа).

Comment: Вроде, и на втором, и на первом одинаково размазанные буквы. Выглядит так, как будто просто разный алгоритм размазывания используется.

Comment: Фактически антиалиасинг это и есть алгоритм размазывания.

Comment: На деле разница значительна - например PT Serif Regular в Sketch и PT Serif Regular в браузере выглядят соответсвенно как Regular и какой то алгоритмически раздутый Bold. И различие это как раз и убриается вышеизлоожеными свойствами.

Comment: Я пересмотрел изображение - различия видимы, попробуйте посмотреть с другого устрйства.

Comment: А что спросить то хотели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему этого нет даже у крупных сервисов - загадка.

Вероятно, потому что это аналог(читать костыль) для свойства `font-smooth`, которое не является стандартом и не рекомендуется к применению в продакшене.